# How can I put large parentheses around a figure?

Tags: graphics, delimiters, parentheses

Around an image, I would like to place parentheses that are large enough to enclose an image. To give you an idea, I tried:

```
\[
 \left(
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figurename}
 \right)
\]
```

However, this does not work, because the parentheses are too small and not properly aligned (too low). Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: the other question deals with braces to the left and below and that requires a completely different treatment, as shown in the answers to that question. Here, the situation is different (parantheses to the left and to the right), and can be handled in a completely different matter. In fact, the solutions given to the other question don't directly apply here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `pmatrix` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\includegraphics{image}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use

```
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
& \includegraphics{image} &
\end{pmatrix}
\]
```

to have some more spacing.

An `array` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\includegraphics{image}
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
{
\includegraphics{image}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.