# Using parentheses around a Qcircuit

Tags: vertical-alignment, qcircuit

I'm trying to draw parentheses around a circuit build using the [qcircuit](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/qcircuit) package, and it seems that the circuits from this package add some white space that is usually compensated in a way, but appears when I inline the circuit with other elements. I'm looking for a solution, be it a clean one or a hack. (The vertical space introduce is proportional to the number of lines of the circuit)
Here is a minimal file of what I'm trying to achieve :

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qcircuit}

\begin{document}
$\left(\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
  & \gate{M} & \qw\\
  & \gate{M} & \qw\\
}\right)$
\end{document}
```

and for now, it yields this :
[image: Compilation result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3):

`qcircuit` (uses `\xymatrix` which) sets the baseline of the diagram to that of the first row, then TeX aligns that to the center of the math axis.  To work around that, you can wrap the environment in `\begin{array}{c} ... \end{array}` (you could also use `\vcenter`, but `\begin{array}` is more LaTeX-y):

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qcircuit}

\begin{document}
$\left(\begin{array}{c}\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
  & \gate{M} & \qw\\
  & \gate{M} & \qw\\
}\end{array}\right)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be broken when the last line only contains a wire, in that case, the gate group solution works better, but this solution has the advantage of being more flexible

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\gategroup`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\begin{document}
$
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
  & \gate{M} & \qw\\
  & \gate{M} & \qw  \gategroup{1}{3}{2}{3}{1.5em}{)} \gategroup{1}{1}{2}{1}{1.5em}{(}
}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A hack I found was to compile the circuit alone, and then use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/how-can-i-put-large-parentheses-around-a-figure) to encapsulate the resulting pdf in parenthesis. I don't really like it but it work for now. I'll let this solution unvalidated for a few day in case someone comes up with a better solution.